# How to extract info from a file

Tags: conceptual

this may be a beginner's question.  I've tried searching for info but couldn't find anything.  Part of my work requires me to convert a specific, proprietary, file type. Unfortunately the software is no longer supported and can't be found.  I have no idea where to start on this.  I would like to write a little utility to basically convert the file for me to a standard file.  Question is where do I start?  Conceptually what am I looking at here?  Is this even possible?

Answer (score -1):

You could start by understanding what is stored in the file. Is there a pattern to the data, what is the pattern, how it is repeated, etc.

Then open the file in binary mode and try to find if there is indeed a pattern. If there is one, you should be able to see it, even if in binary mode.

And lots of patience :-)

Comment: So is this technically reverse engineering? If it is I will start doing my research on how to do this.  I will be learning from new obviously.